# Replacing '\' with "\\" in string C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a "simple" problem with string replacing.

I have an unknown amount of strings that follow a similar system to this:

> 'W8D6m\2alNzPUW2d2m4V9EksLHg='

Notice the '\' in the string, what I want to do is have the program to ignore it and not treat it as an escape character. The error is being thrown from this code

```
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Users\\" + UniqueID, NewUser.ToString());
```

The UniqueID is the string variable that holds the part that is throwing the error as it is thinking both sides of the slash are part of the path. So I am trying to replace it by doing:

```
UniqueID = UniqueID.Replace(@"\", "\\");
```

However that didn't work either, so I am trying to figure out, how can I make the program ignore if the string contains a "\" (it needs to be there, so a simple remove can't be a solution)

If this is all confusing, what I need done is for the 'W8D6m\2alNzPUW2d2m4V9EksLHg=' to think that it is a complete path since it is a file name, not a folder. I want this to be the name of a file. An example is this http://prntscr.com/9tm9ed

Comment: Write it with a speical string like "☺", then convert it back when read it might do the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that you're trying to store a backslash as a file name, which isn't possible. If you could do that, how would the computer know whether or not you're attempting to access a directory or a file?

Your best option is to replace the backslash with another character. You seem to be using the [standard Base64 alphabet](http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html) so I'd suggest the character "-" as it's a common character that isn't used as part of Base64 encoding.

```
uniqueID.Replace(@"\", "-");
```

That character can be replaced by a ton of other characters (*._~ etc) that aren't used in regular Base64 though.

**Make sure to replace the character with a backslash when trying to interpret it, though!**

Comment: Pretty much the only solution here that should work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `\` in this string is that when you concatenate:

```
<Startup>\Users\W8D6m\2alNzPUW2d2m4V9EksLHg=
```

it makes new path with following components:

```
<Startup> \ Users \ W8D6m \ 2alNzPUW2d2m4V9EksLHg=
```

You should not use `*()\` etc characters which has special meaning to construct file/folder names.

Answer (score 0):

You simple can't have "\" in the file name. Write it with a speical string like "☺", then convert it back when read it might do the trick

Comment: Yes, replace the '\', but not the way you have suggested - you have no guarantee that the underlying filesystem is Unicode based (NTFS is, FATxx are not - and you might not even be on Windows) - so using a special Unicode character like ☺ isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is guaranteed to give you a correct file name regardless of input:

```
static string GetValidFileName(string data) 
{
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"W8D6m\2alNzPUW2d2m4V9EksLHg=");
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes).Replace("/", "_");
}
```

Note that replacing just the backslash does not guarantee a valid file name, since there are other characters that are invalid according to the `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` array.

Replacing the backslash from the input string with another string may introduce collisions, e.g. `"hello\world".Replace('\','-')` gives you the same output as `"hello-world"`.

Note that you may still want to check if the path is too long, some APIs limit the number of characters in a path to 260 characters.